# UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups throws exception

Tags: .net

In the following code

```
PrincipalContext* context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType::Domain, domainName);
UserPrincipal* user = UserPrincipal::FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType::SamAccountName, userName);
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal*>* groups = user->GetAuthorizationGroups();
```

I get the following exception:

> Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**Exception call stack:**

```
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.CheckDisposedOrDeleted()
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroupsHelper()
 at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups()
```

Any idea why the internal method fails? How can the user be deleted or disposed, or what has happened?